# Android Studio - add and reference the Google Play services library without Gradle

Tags: android, google-play-services

How can i add "google play services library" to my project that don't use gradle with android studio 0.4.2?

Having troubles with migrating project to gradle. Is there a way to do this without it?

Comment: If you're not using a Gradle-based project, then follow IntelliJ IDEA instructions for adding Play services as in the answer above. If you're having problems migrating a project to Gradle, it's worth a separate question with details including your build.gradle files and the errors you're having.